Segmentation fault on copy custom dynamic array
I'm trying to implement my custom dynamic array, like std::vector.
Dynamic array module code:
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <cstdlib>

#define CAPACITY_SCALE_FACTOR 2

template <typename T>
struct Array
{
  T*      data;
  size_t  size;
  size_t  capacity;

  Array()
  {
    size     = 0;
    capacity = 10;
    data = (T*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(T));
  }

  ~Array()
  {
    free(data);
    data = NULL;
    size = capacity = 0;
  }

  T& operator[](size_t index);
  const T& operator[](size_t index) const;

  Array(const Array &other){
    if (array_size(other))
      for (size_t i = 0; i < other.size; i++)
        array_insert(*this, other[i]);
  }

  Array& operator=(const Array& other) {
    if (array_size(other))
      for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size(other); i++)
        array_insert(*this, other[i]);

    return *this;
  }
};


template <typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](size_t index)
{
  return data[index];
}

template <typename T>
const T& Array<T>::operator[](size_t index) const
{
  return data[index];
}

template <typename T>
size_t array_size(const Array<T> &array)
{
  return array.size;
}

template <typename T>
void array_insert(Array<T> &array, const T value)
{
  array[array.size] = value;

  array.size++;

  if (array.size == array.capacity)
  {
    array.capacity *= CAPACITY_SCALE_FACTOR;
    array.data = (T*)realloc(array.data, array.capacity * sizeof(T));
  }
}

template <typename T>
void array_delete(Array<T> &array, size_t index)
{
  for (size_t i = index; i < array.size - 1; i++)
  {
    array[i] = array[i + 1];
  }

  array.size--;

  if ( array.size <= ( array.capacity / (CAPACITY_SCALE_FACTOR * 2) ) )
  {
    array.capacity =
      (array.size == 0) ? 1 : array.size * CAPACITY_SCALE_FACTOR;

    array.data = (T*)realloc(array.data, array.capacity * sizeof(T));
  }
}

#endif


Usage example code:
#include "array.h"

int main()
{
  Array<char> one = Array<char>();
  array_insert(one, 'C');
  Array<char> two = one;

  return 0;
}

When I try to assign one array to another Array<char> two = one; I receive Segmentation fault (core dumped). I tried to resolve this issue by implemented copy constructor and copy assign operator, but it didn't help.

Your copy constructor is completely wrong since you're manipulating uninitialized member variables.  Also note that malloc won't work if T is non-trivial (e.g., std::string).


Use the member initialization list.  2) (T*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(T)) -- realloc as mentioned will fail miserably if T is non-trivial.  3) operator= leaks memory.  If you're going to try and implement std::vector, you should not be using C techniques such as malloc and realloc -- I am curious as to why they are here, knowing that you are using "advanced" C++ such as templates.


Use the right tools and the program itself can often tell you what went wrong and where: https://godbolt.org/z/WbeWc8Kso . All that leaves for you is figuring out how to fix it.

Also, I suggest you find very simple and working examples of home-made vector classes.  There are just too many issues with the code you have now to go through all of them, unless a rewrite is done as an answer.  I know that it is tempting to try this yourself, but as you can see it is much more intricate than what you expected.

Side note: While it's not always the most efficient solution, the Copy and Swap Idiom is an excellent place to start writing your assignment operator because it is simple and as close to foolproof as you can get in programming. Profiling will tell you if you need something more complicated.

When I try to assign one array to another Array two = one; -- That calls the copy constructor, not assignment.  -- I tried to resolve this issue by implemented copy constructor and copy assign operator -- With the class you wrote, you have no choice but to implement the assignment operator and copy constructor (and destructor).  If you didn't do this, your class would violate the rule of 3.  Go to the Managing resources section of that link, and see a class that is similar to yours that fails.

Other issues -- copy constructor does not initialize the members.  If an empty Array is passed to the copy constructor, the members end up not being initialized.   What if array_size returns 0?  So basically you need to take a step back and go through all of the issues brought up, unless someone can write a compreshensive list of all the issues, the fixes, and place it as an answer (but I bet once those issues are resolved, the code would be changed considerably).  That's the only way to guarantee you do not get crashes with the usage of your class.

Also note that Array<char> one = Array<char>(); is effectively just Array<char> one; In modern C++, there is no assignment in that statement.  In old versions, there was, but not anymore.

Why use malloc and free in C++ ?

@PaulMcKenzie Thank you very much for your comments, really helpful. For your curiosity, I use malloc and realloc cause previously I learned C and they are more familiar for me ^_^

As mentioned in comments, you did not implement your copy constructor and assignment operator correctly, as you are not initializing your class members before using them.  Also, you should not be using malloc()/realloc() at all in C++, as they do not manage non-trivial types correctly. Use new[] and delete[] instead.
Also, in your array_insert(), you are growing the array after adding a new item into it, but you should grow before adding instead.

And, why is array_insert() implemented as a free-standing function instead of being a method of the struct? Same with array_size() and array_delete(), too.

Also, consider using the Copy/Swap Idiom, and standard library functions, to simplify your coding.
Try something more like this:
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
struct Array
{
private:
  static const size_t CAPACITY_SCALE_FACTOR = 2;

  T*      m_data;
  size_t  m_size;
  size_t  m_capacity;

  void swap(Array &other, bool swap_size = true)
  {
    std::swap(m_data,     other.m_data);
    std::swap(m_capacity, other.m_capacity);
    if (swap_size) {
      std::swap(m_size,   other.m_size);
    }
  }

public:
  Array(size_t initial_capacity = 10)
  {
    m_size     = 0;
    m_capacity = initial_capacity;
    m_data     = (m_capacity > 0) ? new T[m_capacity] : nullptr;
  }

  Array(const Array &other)
    : Array(other.m_size)
  {
    std::copy_n(other.m_data, other.m_size, m_data);
    m_size = other.m_size;
  }

  ~Array()
  {
    delete[] m_data;
  }

  Array& operator=(const Array& other)
  {
    if (this != &other) {
      Array(other).swap(*this);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  T& operator[](size_t index) { return m_data[index]; }
  const T& operator[](size_t index) const { return m_data[index]; }

  size_t size() const { return m_size; }
  size_t capacity() const { return m_capacity; }

  void insert(const T &value)
  {
    if (m_size == m_capacity)
    {
      Array<T> temp(m_capacity * CAPACITY_SCALE_FACTOR);
      std::copy_n(m_data, m_size, temp.m_data);
      temp.swap(*this, false);
    }
    m_data[m_size] = value;
    ++m_size;
  }

  void remove(size_t index)
  {
    if (index >= m_size) {
      return; // or better, throw an exception, like std::out_of_range...
    }

    std::copy(m_data + index + 1, m_data + m_size, m_data);
    --m_size;
    m_data[m_size] = T(); // clear unused data

    if (m_size <= (m_capacity / (CAPACITY_SCALE_FACTOR * 2)))
    {
      Array temp(m_size * CAPACITY_SCALE_FACTOR);
      std::copy_n(m_data, m_size, temp.m_data);
      temp.swap(*this, false);
    }
  }
};

#endif

Online Demo
